# how to remove SELinux label?

Tags: linux, fedora, permissions, selinux

I added the SELinux label `svirt_sandbox_file_t` to `/home`

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /home
```

The label is shown using:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ls -Z
unconfined_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0 Desktop
unconfined_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0 Documents
...
```

How can I remove the `svirt_sandbox_file_t` label again?

I tried rebooting, I added a `/home/.autorelabel` to trigger relabeling, but the label won't go away. I am using Fedora 23.

Comment: Do you have any other custom labels on there? My understanding is that `restorecon` would restore the original state as defined in the global policy, but my SELinux knowledge is handwavy at best.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I am not aware of any other custom labels. I tried `restorecon` but this did not help either.

Comment: Did you run `restorecon` recursively as well? That should reset the label. It must be run as root if you need to reset other accounts as well. The `.autorelabel` file needs to go in `/`. But I doubt that will have any other effect than `restorecon -R` inthis case. Except when `/home` is a symlink.

Comment: @Bram `/home` is a separate partition. I tried running recursively but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you set `/etc/selinux/config` to `disabled` reboot. Then set it to `enforcing` and reboot, it will re-label if you've had trouble getting it to relabel otherwise. It's weird that restorecon didn't work though.

If you want to reset things the hard way, the /home directory itself should be:

```
system_u:object_r:home_root_t
```

and each user home directory (and the files within it) should be:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0
```

You can set these with either the `chcon` command, or using a combination of `semanage` and `restorecon`

```
chcon -t home_root_t /home
chcon -Rt user_home_dir_t /home/*
```

or

```
 semanage fcontext -a -t home_root_t /home
 semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_dir_t /home/*
 restorecon -R /home
```

please note that *generally speaking* `chcon` is used to force an immediate change, while leaving the defaults in place, so that a `restorecon` will restore it to the default contexts. In your case that seems to have gone wrong for some reason.

Generally `semanage fcontext` is intended to write a local context file to `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local`

a wealth of information on the current context, and default context's can be found in:

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/default_contexts
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs
```

It is possible that somehow those files were somehow damaged, and overall there are many sub contexts that may not be fully restored by the above actions depending on how those files have been modified. It may be a good idea to examine those files and see if you can find your added context mapping and remove it that way as well.

Theoretically you could also take a virtual machine, or another machine(or perhaps just find them online) and copy the known good defaults into their proper directories, and allow the system to relabel in order to get the proper defaults. This too will have some short comings though.

At the end of the day a bit of trial and error will be necessary, the chcon/semanage commands listed above should give you the broad strokes, but its possible some of your sub directories will have their own contexts.

Some additional contexts that may be helpful(all of these are in /home/username would be:

`ls -laZ /home/username`

```
##context###########################  Directory##
unconfined_u:object_r:cache_home_t:s0 .cache
unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0 .config
unconfined_u:object_r:dbus_home_t:s0 .dbus
unconfined_u:object_r:gconf_home_t:s0 .gconf
unconfined_u:object_r:gconf_home_t:s0 .gconfd
unconfined_u:object_r:gpg_secret_t:s0 .gnupg
unconfined_u:object_r:gconf_home_t:s0 .local
unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .ssh
```

Please note that this is based on my home directory, there will be more that you may have to hunt down, but if you get most of those correct, you should  be more or less back on track.

Comment: How would I reset "the hard way"? I tried disabling selinux, rebooting, enabling, rebooting but this did not change anything.

Comment: @m.s. added additional information in the answer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `chcon -Rt user_home_dir_t /home/*` did the trick for me, thanks for the great answer!